update 23 to 24 using live-usb iso?
I have Ubuntu 23 and I will update it to 24. I have no enough space in partition for auto-update, therefore I created an image with 24 in usb-stick. Is there any way to update my system from live-usb? With saving my data (root and home in unified parition).

No, there isn't. Except this, updating 23.04 -> 24.04 is not a supported upgrade path, one STS releases of Ubuntu only support upgrading to the next version and not jumping one or more releases in between.

Does this answer your question? How to install new version of Ubuntu and keep home partition untouched and Can I skip over releases when upgrading?

Thank you, but actually I can update from 23 to 24.  Perhaps this was impossible before. But now the automatic update program offers me this. The only problem now is that I don’t have enough space on my hard drive to download the update. So I would like to know if it is possible to upgrade the system from a flash drive containing 24 ubuntu.

You can update from a live USB while keeping your data. Just follow these steps:
Boot from the Ubuntu 24 live USB.
Choose the "Install Ubuntu" option.
When prompted, select "Something else" to manually partition.
Find your existing root partition and choose it for the new installation.
Ensure "Format" is not checked for your root partition.
Complete the installation.
This will update your system while preserving your data. Make sure to back up important files just in case. Good luck!
Ubuntu Official Documentation: Ubuntu Installation Guide
and How to upgrade Ubuntu using a live USB?

Thank you. But in 24 installation setup each step has another name.  It is not problem, but it impossible to choose partition with 23 for update.Unfortunately I do not know how to attach to this comment photos from the installer

In latest ISO, it won't let you continue unless you set the '/' mount point, but if you do, option to "Leave formatted as Ext4" disappears and there is only "Ext4" and then the "Format" is checked and CAN'T be unchecked I read on forum there is some bug in the installer so they turned it off - be careful if you don't want to delete your data...
